# Enumeration of Trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Find the number of trees of $n$ vertices in which a given vertex is a leaf.

I am having difficulty understanding what this question wants me to find.

We know the total amount of trees with $n$ vertices is $n^{n-2}$.

If it is asking how many trees of these have a vertex $v_i$ as a leaf, then by a corollary to Cayley's Formula, this would be $(n-2)!/\prod{(d_i -1)!}$. Am I interpreting the question correctly?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't it just the number of trees with $n-1$ vertices? [Take such a tree and add on a leaf to get a tree of $n$ vertices.]

Comment: Hmm yes this makes sense and is very straightfoward. Thank you.

Comment: @angryavian: No, it isn’t. There is $1$ labelled tree on $2$ vertices, but there are $2$ labelled trees on $3$ vertices having vertex $3$ as a leaf.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oops, I should have added "multiplied by $n-1$ for the number of ways to attach the leaf," right?

Comment: @angryavian: Yes.